# Send <input type="file"> content from client side to server side

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm modifying an app which control the entity maintenance via jsp forms. That's ok, but the main entity (Contrato) has many other maintenances in it's own form, and my customer does not want redirects in the middle, so I must change all the jsp secondary maintenances by modals / javascript and jquery.

There are no problems so far untill now when I'm trying to manage files:

In former jsp view i have a `<form:input>`:

```
<form:input path ="documento" type="file" name="Documento"/>
```

Then, I have a helper java class with the attribute:

```
private MultipartFile documento;
```

Here MultipartFile is received perfectly when mapping the request.

Now I have a modal for this maintenance with an `<input>`

```
<input id="documento" name="documento" type="file" style="width: 100%">
```

If i request `documento` in java i get an string:

```
C:\fakepath\file.ext
```

After more attempts, using `FileReader` i'm able to store in a variable the `URL` of the file:

```
function handleFileSelect(event) {
    input = event.target;
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    }
}
```

Now debugging, i can see `arrayBuffer` variable is:

> data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJbXtrvsKMyAwIG9iago8PCAvTGVuZ3RoIDQ…QgMTAxMSAwIFIKICAgL0luZm8gMTAxMCAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjIxMTYzMgolJUVPRgo.....

Which is a valid `URL` with the file. But when i try to send it to my `@RequestMapping` as `@RequestParam`:

```
@RequestParam(value="file",required=false,defaultValue="0") Object file,

http://localhost:8080/my/url/documentoSubmit?file=data%3Aap…MTQ2MSAwIFIKICAgL0luZm8gMTQ2MCAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjMwMTc4MgolJUVPRgo%3D...
```

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Petición incorrecta)

How can I send the `javascript URL` to java server side to persist it in DB?

Comment: You POST the form that the field is in, or else you use the File API to read the file contents (with JavaScript) and send it with an ajax POST.

Comment: @Pointy There is no form, just a modal... I've tryed with javascript File API but I just succeed with Images, for other files (like pdf or excel sheets which i think must be BLOB) does not clarify so much for me....  You know any examples? TX